# Покраска кнопок через input type color

Tags: javascript, html

Есть кнопки, которые красятся через input type color. Вопрос в том как сделать чтоб они красились в исходный цвет, то есть серый, при повторном нажатии и если выбран тот же цвет

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  var idColor = document.getElementById('idColor').value;
  if_id = e . target. id;

  the_class = e . target.className;

  if(the_class == "click_me")

  {

    if_id = document.getElementById(if_id);

    if(if_id .style . background == idColor)

    {

      if_id .style . background = "#efefef";

    }

    else

    {
      if_id .style . background = idColor;
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<label>
Choose color:
<input type="color" id="idColor">
</label>
  
<button class="click_me" id="id_1">Измени цвет кнопки</button>

<button class="click_me" id="id_2">Измени цвет кнопки</button>

<button class="click_me" id="id_3">Измени цвет кнопки</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.click_me');
  const colorSet = document.getElementById('idColor');
  const defCol = '#c0c0c0'; // 192
  const butColors = [];

  function toHex (color) {
    if (!color) return '';
    color = color.replace('rgb(', '');
    color = color.replace(')', '');
    color = color.split(',');
    color = '#' + color.map(c => {
      let n = Number(c).toString(16);
      if (n.length === 1) n = '0' + n;
      return n;
    }).join('')

    return color;
  }

  buttons.forEach((item, index) => {
    butColors.push(item.style.background ? item.style.background : defCol)
    item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      let color = toHex(e.currentTarget.style.background);
      if (color !== colorSet.value) {
        const forCh = color ? color : defCol;
        e.currentTarget.style.background = colorSet.value;
        butColors[index] = forCh;
      } else {
        e.currentTarget.style.background = butColors[index];
        butColors[index] = colorSet.value;
      }
    })
  })
```

```html
<label>
  Choose color:
  <input type="color" id="idColor">
</label>
<button class="click_me" id="id_1">Измени цвет кнопки</button>
<button class="click_me" id="id_2">Измени цвет кнопки</button>
<button class="click_me" id="id_3">Измени цвет кнопки</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать добавив переключатель:

```js
const newBGColor = document.querySelector('#idColor');
const oldBGColor = 'white';
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.click_me');

document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const target = e.target;
  
  if (!target.classList.contains('click_me')) return;
  
  if (target.dataset.changed === '1') {
    target.dataset.changed = '0';
    target.style.backgroundColor = oldBGColor;
    
    return;
  }
  
  target.dataset.changed = '1';
  target.style.backgroundColor = newBGColor.value;
});
```

```html
<label>
Choose color:
<input type="color" id="idColor">
</label>
  
<button class="click_me" id="id_1">Измени цвет кнопки</button>

<button class="click_me" id="id_2">Измени цвет кнопки</button>

<button class="click_me" id="id_3">Измени цвет кнопки</button>
```